# Get a service input as an XML from extranel java class in webmethods

Tags: java, webmethods

I need to extract the XML schema of inputs for specific webmethods flow service from external java class.

It's like when you run a flow service in designer; a new window appears containing all inputs and you can save it in external file as a pipeline. I'm tring to do the same thing form external java class. That is, get the input --> transfer to XML --> save it in file.

I can get the inputs names but not there structure (for record type as exp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally;

1. You have to find the signatures nodes
2. Use IDataUtility to delete what is not record.
3. Use IDataUtility to include the empty fields

thanks